# Getting error when trying to use camera package from pub dev

Tags: flutter, dart, package, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

The plugin `camera_android` doesn't have a main class defined in

> C:\Users\Emerge\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\camera_android-0.10.8+14\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\CameraPlugin.java
> or
> C:\Users\Emerge\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\camera_android-0.10.8+14\android\src\main\kotlin\io\flutter\plugins\camera\CameraPlugin.kt. This is likely to due to an incorrect `androidPackage: io.flutter.plugins.camera` or `mainClass` entry in the plugin's
> pubspec.yaml. If you are the author of this plugin, fix the
> `androidPackage` entry or move the main class to any of locations used
> above. Otherwise, please contact the author of this plugin and
> consider using a different plugin in the meanwhile.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiWi6.png)

tried to use camera package.

Comment: have you tried flutter clean and rebuild?

Comment: Yes.@AntonyAiwinKX